# Como eu faço para concatenar um parâmetro (String) em um caminho de Objeto para acessar uma Response?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Olá, estou tentando acessar um caminho vindo da response baseado no nome do parâmetro que envio via OnClick (estou usando AngularJS para isso). Não consigo concatenar o parametro recebido no caminho da minha Response, já tentei converter em OBJ ou em String e o maximo que consegui foi o retorno de [obj obj]Param ( sendo que tinha que retornar a resposta do servidor). No caso estou tentando concatenar o paramentro champion (enviado do OnClick) na resposta do servidor, algo como response.data.data + {champion}+ '.id'

Porem nao consigo nenhum retorno atraves desse tipo de concatenacao, tentei ate dar split e juntar tudo porem ele continua lendo como string,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$scope.search = function (champion) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/champion/' + champion + '.json'
        }).then(function sucessCallBack(response) {
            let name = "response.data.data"
            let splitName = name.split(".")
            let splitName2 = splitName.join(".")
            console.log(response.data.data);
            let champions = response.data.data + '.' + champion + '.id'; 
            console.log(champions)
        }).then(function errorCallBack(response) {
        
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

O que essa linha retorna?

```
console.log(response.data.data);
```

Dê uma olhadinha nessa pergunta e veja se lhe é útil:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246725/cant-convert-json-to-array-in-angular-js

Comment: Entáo ele retorna basicamente um JSON com os dados do campeão, vou fixar na pergunta para melhor me ajudar.

Comment: Tente assim:

response.data.data[champion].id